# How to solve MD5sum version error?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using
Windows7: MATLAB R2020a
Ubuntu 18.04: ROS melodic, UR3 in Gazebo
My code is
[urArm, urGoalMsg] = rosactionclient('arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory');
Error message of ROS is
[ERROR] [1523601174.867179119, 8.956000000]: Client [/matlab_global_node_65047] wants topic /arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result to have datatype/md5sum [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/bce83d50f7bb28226801436caf0e2043], but our version has [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/c4fb3b000dc9da4fd99699380efcc5d9]. Dropping connection.

how can I solve this. I tried deleting devel and build files and catkin_make again. It didn't work. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358596/how-to-solve-md5sum-version-error-?/) by [HELPme](https://answers.ros.org/users/57287/helpme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) on 2020-08-04**:
Can you please post more information about your issue. I don't see a proper error message in there.

**Comment by [HELPme](https://answers.ros.org/users/57287/helpme/) on 2020-08-12**:
I'm using
Windows7: MATLAB R2020a
Ubuntu 18.04: ROS melodic, UR3 in Gazebo
My code is
[urArm, urGoalMsg] = rosactionclient('arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory');
Error message of ROS is

[ERROR] [1523601174.867179119, 8.956000000]: Client [/matlab_global_node_65047] wants topic /arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result to have datatype/md5sum

[control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/bce83d50f7bb28226801436caf0e2043], but our version has [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/c4fb3b000dc9da4fd99699380efcc5d9]. Dropping connection.

how can I solve this. I tried deleting devel and build files and catkin_make again. It didn't work. Please help

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-08-12**:
The msg definitions might be different. Easiest way to check if what you get is what you expected is to do a `rosmsg info`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here appears to be that your Matlab ROS support uses a different version of the `control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult` message than your ROS Melodic install.

The error message about the MD5 sums no matching is telling you this.

As to *why* this is the case I wouldn't know. `control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction` hasn't changed in many years, so it's unclear to me how this could happen.

As to how to fix this (or work-around it): I would suggest you ask Mathworks for support. Assuming you haven't made any changes to `ros-melodic-control-msgs` on your Ubuntu machine, the problem would seem to be on the side of Matlab.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-12**:
As a guess: *perhaps* Matlab is using `rosjava`, in which case this *might* be caused by [rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap#16](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/issues/16), but again: just a guess

**Comment by [HELPme](https://answers.ros.org/users/57287/helpme/) on 2020-08-13**:
thnx for the help.